# RavenDB Index covering single as well as list of objects within a document

Tags: ravendb

Scenario:

I am currently creating a search feature within our site. This feature is to return an album that matches all of the given criteria. Ie. Album Title, Composer, etc. I know a little about the full text search that is within Raven, and I might have to end up trying to use that.

I was hoping though that I might would be able to use a single index instead and just query against the index. (Unfortunately I am not knowledgeable enough at this time to say why I should/should not do this versus the full text index, so I am open to suggestions :))

Something worth Noting...The Album is the only collection that we currently have in Raven, as it is provided to raven via a data import from an alternate system. It can be thought of as a denormalized view of everything related to an album.

Below is an example of our Album:

```
public class Album
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<string> Composers { get; set; }
    public List<string> MusicCategories { get; set; }
    public List<string> PerformingGroups { get; set; }
    public List<string> Instruments { get; set; }            
}
```

Below is the Index that I attempted to create. The title search works but no results are being returned when I search for an item within a collection. I can only imagine it has to do with the fact that I am not doing any type of map/reduce and projection on them. But that is just a guess on my part.

```
ravenSessionManager.DocumentStore.DatabaseCommands
            .PutIndex("AlbumsBySearchCriteria", new IndexDefinitionBuilder<Album>
            {
                Map = albums => from a in albums
                                select
                                    new
                                    {
                                        a.Title,
                                        a.Composers,
                                        a.MusicCategories,
                                        a.Instruments
                                    },
                Indexes =
                                                      {
                                                          {x => x.Title, FieldIndexing.Analyzed},
                                                          {x => x.Composers, FieldIndexing.Analyzed},FieldIndexing.Analyzed},
                                                          {x => x.MusicCategories, FieldIndexing.Analyzed},FieldIndexing.Analyzed},
                                                          {x => x.Instruments, FieldIndexing.Analyzed}

                                                      }
            });
```

And finally below is an example of my query:

```
 var query = (from a in _documentSession.Query<Album>("AlbumsBySearchCriteria")
                         select a);

            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria.Title))
                query = query.Where(a => a.Title.StartsWith(criteria.Title));
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria.Composer))
                query = query.Where(a => a.Composers.Any(c => c.StartsWith(criteria.Composer)));
return query;
```

Thanks in advance for any help/guidance that you can offer. Any help or advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: I am completely new to RavenDB and Lucene, but I would have expected this to work.  I've dug into the RavenDB source code just to learn a bit about using Lucene.NET, and I thought RavenDB would give Lucene one Consumers field per element in your Consumers list.

Comment: Yeah me too :). The odd thing is, both I and another dev here would swear we had this working just a few days ago, because we had tested it religiously. Now for some reason, it is not working. And according to our source control no changes have been made :). I am currently attempting Daniel's suggestion below. It is working if i only enter one criteria per search, but failing with multiple criteria. i will make sure to update if I get it working. Thanks for  looking into this and commenting. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I have figured out the issue that I was facing, and I thought I would share some context and allow others to see the mistakes that I had made. First of all I would like to say thanks to Daniel for his answer. His solution does and will work just fine. It is also worth mentioning that my original solution will work too, as long as you don't make the dumb mistakes that I did :).

**Mistake #1**: My solution originally appeared to fail due to a new ETL of documents that I was not aware of, and an old incorrect index. Unfortunately I was to "in the weeds" to notice.

**Mistake # 2**: Daniels example was not exactly what I needed so I had to do a little tweaking, and while tweaking I forgot to put the "As<'dynamic'>" onto my query like Daniel's example has.

If you want to act on the results of your query as the original clr-type that the document  is saved as **and** your index does not return that same type, then it is important to either add "As<'dynamic'>()" or "AsProjection<'SomeType'>()" to your query. Because, when queried Raven will cast the clr-type of the document to the clr-type that you specify within your index. Which in my case is exactly what happened. I wanted to act on my results as type Album, but my documents being returned from the query were changing from type "Album" to "ReduceResult" as one would actually expect. What I did not expect is that it would flag a change in the document that it had changed, and if SaveChanges() was called, it would now save my document as the new type. Which leads me to mistake number 3.

**Mistake # 3**: Everything that I was doing was in a "Unit of Work" pattern and I had forgotten that at the end of my http request I called a ravenSession.SaveChanges(). This is what sealed my fate :(. Because my types were changed during the querying mentioned in mistake 2, I now found myself having documents within the same collection that were  different clr-types.

The end result was that every time that I performed a search on my index that returned back multiple documents having different clr-types, I would get an invalid cast exception. To make things worse I caught all of my exceptions so that I could handle them appropriately and return specific results back to the calling client. Because of this my SaveChanges() always fired, and thus adding documents back to my album collection with a different clr-type. And the circle  of frustration continued.

So using my example, my recommendation would be...

1. If you want to use/act on an Album within your code, make sure your index either brings back the document as an Album, or have your index bring back what ever reduce result tye that you want, but ensure that you add the As<'dynamic'>() or AsProjection<'Sometype'>() method onto your query. This should prevent the result from changing the document clr-type.
2. Make sure you do not have any session.SaveChanges() being called that you have forgotten about.
3. Always check your indexes to make sure they are up to date.

In short, don't make the same stupid mistakes that I did. Apparently my ignorance has no bounds :)

Thanks again to both of the Daniels that responded. I appreciate the help.